# Why can I not load data from beginning.zip file

Tags: r

I am trying to load my R file but it keeps reading as errors and

[image]

> Error in source("C:/Users/masters/OneDrive/Desktop/GCU/Business Analyst/Business Analyst/MIS-650/Beginning.csv") : 
>     C:/Users/masters/OneDrive/Desktop/GCU/Business Analyst/Business Analyst/MIS-650/Beginning.csv:1:3: unexpected input
>   1: PK
>
> loading through the Rstudio file open file method.

I am using the [Default] [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2 version, please help.

Comment: Please check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add the concrete information needed to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `read.csv`

Something like this:

```
df <- read.csv('C:/Users/masters/OneDrive/Desktop/GCU/Business Analyst/Business Analyst/MIS-650/Beginning.csv')
```

Comment: The data is still pulling up as PK

Comment: Your file might be encoded in UTF-16. If so, you could try: `df <- read.csv('C:/Users/masters/OneDrive/Desktop/GCU/Business Analyst/Business Analyst/MIS-650/Beginning.csv', skipNul = TRUE, fileEncoding='UTF-16LE')`